# Linq Query where condition not handling nulls

Tags: vb.net

```
 Dim query = (From row In dataTable.AsEnumerable() _
             Where row.Field(Of String)("SomeColumn") = "Y"
             Select AnothereDataTable.LoadDataRow(New Object() {row.Field(Of Decimal?)("coloum1"), _
                    row.Field(Of String)("Column2")},True))
```

I have the above linq query where I am filtering the datatable on "SomeColumn" with condition equals to "Y". The "SomeColumn" may also contain nulls because of that the when I am trying to take query.Count() I get the exception "Object not set to an instance" but if there are no nulls in the "SomeColumn" the query returns perfect. I have also tried with the below codes but didn't worked

```
Where Object.equals(row.Field(Of String)("SomeColumn")="Y")
Where row.Field(Of String)("SomeColumn").Equals("Y")
```

Comment: Side-Note: LINQ Queries should never cause side effects. `LoadDataRow` fills another table and returns the added row. That's a good example for a bad LINQ query. Due to deferred execution you would now always add rows when you touch this query. Instead query what you want to add. Then use a `For each` to add these rows.

Comment: I am copying few particular columns into another datatable using query.CopyToDataTable() so I am using LoadDataRow